# Puppet Modules - Best Practices for Installing External Modules and Downloading Packages

Tags: git, puppet

I wrote this small puppet module:
https://github.com/entheologist/puppetmods-bioperl

Which installs a package called BioPerl. Now I'm writing a module to install another package (Ensembl Perl API) which depends on the BioPerl package so I have to make sure this package is installed first.

How do module authors usually install package dependencies? I could install puppet, and run `puppet module install {vendor-package}` but something tells me that would be very bad practice. I could also clone the git repository of the module into the modules directory, but I get the feeling theres a better way to do it than that. Is it bad practice to clone git repositories from within your module?

Heres the `init.pp` file of the module I've made so far:
http://pastebin.com/mRGCEsy1

Its quite messy with all of these downloading archives, extracting them and deleting them. It would be a whole lot cleaner to use the `puppet-archive` module to handle all the downloading and extracting of archives, but I need to install that module before I can use it. How do module authors tend to go about installing external modules that their modules depend on?

Comment: If you have enterprise and are managing a master: https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/code_mgr.html. If you do not have enterprise, or want an alternative, and are managing a master: https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/r10k.html. If you are doing masterless puppet or are only interested in managing your one module independent of the others: https://github.com/voxpupuli/librarian-puppet. Check those out and let me know what looks appealing.

Comment: I'm trying to turn this into a module that I can upload to `forge.puppet.com`, so other people can use it, so with that in mind I have to make it as independent as possible. I'm running puppet enterprise, but the next person who uses the module might not be. `librarian-puppet` is brilliant for installing modules, but would requiring it as a dependency be bad practice?

Comment: You don't have to worry about how other people will grab dependencies of your module. As long as you specify them in the `metadata.json`, it becomes other people's responsibility to manage their module deployments with software or through manual methods. Make your decision for your needs based on what works best for you.